# Overwrite wordpress theme page by plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to overwrite a theme page using my custom wordpress plugin , i tried to add filter but without result , i don't want to change directly on the theme because it's bad idea for every developer.
this is my plugin code 
i added a filter to check pages

```
public function __construct(){
    add_filter('theme_file_path','customize_theme_pages', 99, 2 );
}
```

and i tried to replace theme page with my custom page like that

```
public function customize_theme_pages($path, $file = ''){
        if( 'woocommerce/checkout--/form-checkout.php' === $file ) {
            return plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'inc/form-checkout.php';
        }
        return $path;
}
```

it seems logical solution for me , but there is no changes in my site

Comment: Why not use a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead?

Comment: does this code work using child theme ?

Comment: Try yourself and let us know. If it doesn't, we can help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_locate_template` filter to override a woocommerce template file from your plugin.

A quick example, assuming you want to override `checkout/form-checkout.php` with your plugin's `inc/checkout/form-checkout.php` file:

```
function customize_theme_pages($template, $template_name, $template_path) {
    if ($template_name == 'checkout/form-checkout.php') {
        $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/checkout/form-checkout.php';
    }
    return $template;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'customize_theme_pages', 99, 3);
```

**I have tested above code, and it's working on *WooCommerce Version 3.5.0* running on *WordPress 4.9.8*.

If you want you replace a standard page template, you can use `page_template` filter.

Comment: thank you , but my problem is that the theme has page which modify the woocommerce template ,and i want to customize this page, i'll try with 'page_template'

Comment: `woocommerce_locate_template` will work for any woocommerce template from your plugin.